# Update database table with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update for some products their category in database. I want to find products that have in their name a specific word and after that I want to update the category for this products.

I want to select IDs from `sho_posts` where `sho_posts.post_title` contain this part of word `'%Audio CD%'` and after that to update the `sho_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id` with value 2 where `sho_term_relationships.object_id=sho_posts.id`.

I wrote a little PHP code but it make only selection part. What is wrong?

```
 <?php


$username = "user_name";
$password = "password";
$hostname = "host";

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
    or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

$selected = mysql_select_db("1812233_shoping",$dbhandle)
    or die("Could not select examples");
echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";
$result = mysql_query ("SELECT `id` FROM `sho_posts` WHERE CONVERT(`post_title` USING utf8) LIKE '%Audio CD%' ");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "ID:".$row{'id'}."<br>";
}

$sql =  "UPDATE 'sho_term_relationships'
   SET 'term_taxonomy_id' = '123'
 WHERE 'object_id' = $row";
//close the connection
mysql_close($dbhandle);
```

My new cod for script now is:

```
$username = "_shoping";
$password = "password";
$hostname = "localhost";

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
    or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

$selected = mysql_select_db("_shoping",$dbhandle)
    or die("Could not select examples");
echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";
$result = mysql_query ("SELECT `id` FROM `sho_posts` WHERE CONVERT(`post_title` USING utf8) LIKE '%Audio CD%' ");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $id[] = $row['id'];
    /*echo "ID2:".$id."<br>";*/
}


foreach ($id as $value) {
    echo "value:".$value."<br>";
}

/*$id = $row['id'];*/
$sql =  "UPDATE sho_term_relationships
         SET term_taxonomy_id = '123'
         WHERE object_id =".$value;
mysql_query($sql);
//close the connection
mysql_close($dbhandle);
```

now it make an update but only for one row, how to make for all rows? From select query I get 4 result

Comment: Remove the quotes around the table name and the column name in the update sql

Comment: if I do it then is an error : syntax error, unexpected ''sho_term_relationships'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in...

Comment: Just noticed $row is an object. Use $row{'id'}

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sql =  "UPDATE sho_term_relationships
         SET term_taxonomy_id = '123'
         WHERE object_id = ".$row{'id'};
```

And make sure to run the query `mysql_query($sql)`

Also, I think you might want to add this query inside the `while` loop

Comment: It's a little different. Not using quotes on table name, column name and setting the value of the field to an object property as opposed to the entire $row object

Comment: The variable wouldn't be parsed correctly out of the string like that. Instead you need to do `[...] WHERE object_id = ".$row{'id'};`

Comment: @Mike nothing happens, no changes in database

Comment: You probably should have pinged @AlexTartan since he's the one who posted the answer, not me.

Comment: @TatarJony, did you put `mysql_query($sql)` after the $sql = ... ?

Answer (score 0):

You are using single quotes instead of backticks (which are in this case not necessary).  Change your update query to this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE sho_term_relationships
SET term_taxonomy_id = 123
WHERE object_id = $row";
```

Also, you are missing some pieces of your code;  nothing will be called on that query.  It's not being executed at all.

Also you have some other problems here, mainly due to the high risk of sql injection.  First of all **stop using `mysql_` functions, they are deprecated.**   You should prepare your variables.  Here's a demonstration of the key parts of your script in `mysqli_` format.

This should also solve ***most*** of your issues (there may be a few more if I don't full understand your original question).

You would call your database like this  (and check for errors)

```
$dbhandle = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password);
    if  ($dhandle->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $dbhandle->connect_error);
}
```

Then you would select your data like this (assuming that term might not be the same every time, and might be coming from a post variable named `search`).

**Edit:**  For example, if you have an HTML form that is getting this variable like so:

```
<input type="select" name="search_term" />
```

you name the variable like this:

```
$search = $_POST['search_term'];
```

and then you set it up for your query for the `like` operator

```
$search_term = '%'.$search.'%';
$result = $dbhandle->prepare("SELECT `id` 
                          FROM `sho_posts` 
                          WHERE CONVERT(`post_title` USING utf8) 
                          LIKE ? ");
$result->bind_param("s",$search_term);
$result->execute();
$result->bind_result($id);
```

And then you can get your data through the while loop like so

```
while ($result->fetch())  {
   ... stuff you want to do here...
}
$result->close();
```

Then you would use this in your update query (which would take a similar syntax), and you can just get the information from $id which was created with the bind_result above:

```
$sql = $dbhandle->("UPDATE sho_term_relationships
        SET term_taxonomy_id = 123
        WHERE object_id = ?");
$sql->bind_param("s",$id);
$sql->execute();
$sql->close();
```

It may take a little bit to get used to this, but I find it easier to parse, and also is much more secure

Comment: I get the error "Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in..."

Comment: This occurs usually with a bad query. I need the full error

Comment: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /srv/disk8/34444/www/localhost.com/shop/scriptik.php on line 14
that is all what I get

Comment: $result = $dbhandle->prepare("SELECT `id`

Comment: did you define `search_term`?  In other words is it coming from a post variable?  (that's how the `?` is being defined).  If not, you can just query your original item (as you had it in your original) and remove the bind_param row.  If so, echo `$search_term` to see what is in it

Comment: Sure I can try. I can't write the entire script for you, but I can try and help point you in the right direction :)

Comment: sorry, I am confused, I dont understand what I need to do. I am new in sql/php. Can you please help me with this? I will explain one more time.
I have to table sho_posts and sho_term_relationships. Firs of all I what to extract ID's for each item from table sho_posts where post_title contain in it as a part words "Audio CD". After that I want to make an  update in table sho_term_relationships at field term_taxonomy_id with some value for example "2" where object_id from sho_term_relationships is equal with ID from sho_posts that I have selected earlier.

Comment: you would want to call your update within an `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { }` type of conditional

Comment: with script that I wrote, selection from data base work fine and returned the good result. Now I need to store this result in one variable to use it for update. Here come the problem, first I dont know how to store result in variable ant how to implement it after that in update query

Comment: ok, you are almost there.   Basically with what I showed you, you can create the variable you need within this `while ($result->fetch())  { $id = $search_term; }`   that would tie the query variable to the update one

Comment: you can do something like this in your original query with `$id = $row['id']`.  I'd still move forward to this prepared method though

Comment: ok, now it make an update but only for one row, how to make for all rows. From select query I get 4 result.

Comment: ok good.  now for that you need to use a `foreach` loop.   http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php.  you will need to use an array like structure to your variables.   see the link.   also try this:  http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_loop_foreach

Comment: now my code is something like this:
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    echo "ID2:".$id."<br>";
}

foreach ($id as $value) {
    echo "value:".$value."<br>";
}
but it comes an error :Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: try this in the while loop:  `$id[] = $row['id'];`

Comment: no the error disappeared but my script change only one row from 4, the last one.

Comment: That would most likely be because you are already iterating through the rest.  (or something else)  can you add your updated code to your original post, at the end (maybe with an edit notice), so I can see?  (Note I may be heading out in a bit, but will come back later or tomorrow to see)

Comment: sorry for bother, have you looked at the new code that I added? Thank you

Comment: ok, it looks like what I thought.  You are already looping through it before you do your update.  Your while loop is going through all of the values, so there are none left.  Try removing the `echo` and moving the update inside the foreach loop.  Also, for the record, you are still using deprecated and dangerous code. You really need to read up on the prepared statements.  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php